# Running behat test under different browsers

Tags: selenium, behat, mink

I want run behat tests in certain browsers so when I type something like this `bin/behat firefox` or `bin/behat chrome` or `bin/behat opera` tests should be run under respective browsers. Is it possible? If so, how should I modify my yml below or anything else? The reason I need such thing is that the selenium sometimes doesn't like some browsers based on its version.

I read thru [this post](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/38) but I didn't quiet get it to apply to my behat.yml

**behat.yml**:

```
default:
    context:
        class: Football\LeagueBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
        parameters:
            output_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/report/behat/output/
            screen_shot_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/report/behat/screenshot/
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://symfony.local/app_test.php/'
            files_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/dummy/
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: %behat.paths.base%/src
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context
```

**example feature**

```
Feature: Visit Home Page
  In order to see hello message
  As a user
  I should be able to visit home page

  #SUCCESS
  @javascript
  Scenario: I visit home page
    When I go to "/"
    Then I should see "Hello Symfony!"

  #FAIL
  @javascript
  Scenario: I visit home page
    When I go to "/"
    Then I should not see "Hello Behat!"
```

Comment: What exactly happens when "selenium doesn't like some browsers based on its version"? And why the posted github link doesn't apply to your case? I would agree with what is said there…

Comment: Selenium version 2.41.0 stopped running Firefox on my Ubuntu and Mac so I had to either update it or use Chrome ddriver instead. Also I didn't mean to say GitHub link doesn't apply to my case. What I meant was how can I apply that to my behat.yml file. I'll update OP to get rid of misunderstanding.

Comment: In short description; I want to modify my yml in a way that I can run behat to use specific browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation sucks again and again, so you'll need to play around with the config. I'm sure there are a few ways you can achieve this, but the proposed way with profiles should be the simplest. If I get everything correctly it can be done like this.

```
default:
    context:
        class: Football\LeagueBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext
        parameters:
            output_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/report/behat/output/
            screen_shot_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/report/behat/screenshot/
    extensions:
        Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
            mink_driver: true
            kernel:
                env: test
                debug: true
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            base_url: 'http://symfony.local/app_test.php/'
            files_path: %behat.paths.base%/test/dummy/
            browser_name: firefox
            goutte: ~
            selenium2: ~
    paths:
        features: %behat.paths.base%/src
        bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/Context

chrome:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            browser_name: chrome

firefox:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
            browser_name: firefox
```

I'm not 100% certain, but I remember that Behat merges default profile with the other ones, so hopefully you don't have to copy everything, if that doesn't work, then try defining the complete profile.

Also, have a look at [this comment](https://github.com/Behat/Behat/issues/38#issuecomment-1573348), you can define what tags to include with each profile, which might be quite useful if you want only certain tests running in certain browsers.

To run it you specify the profile:

```
$ behat -p firefox
$ behat -p chrome
```

Comment: It worked perfectly fine however I have now my own issue with cromedriver. The selenium 2.43.1 says "chromedriver: cannot execute binary file". I did `chmod +x` and `chmod 777` to it but no luck. While trying to sort it out, I'll accept your answer cos it solves the actual question. Thanks +1

Comment: Try updating your chrome this might be the reason. I'm using 2.43.0 with no problems (on Mac).

Comment: I was using ubuntu version of chromedriver. Just downloaded Mac version and worked fine. I sometimes confuse myself cos I use Ubuntu at home and Mac at work!

Comment: PS: `brew install selenium-server-standalone chromedriver` + `selenium-server -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: @IanBytchek can we use the same browser chrome in different profiles?

Comment: @IanBytchek did you ever manage to solve this ?